# Python Instabot Cant login to my business account, Limits Reached

Tags: python, api, instagram-api

So I am trying to schedule posts to my business account, using python Instabot but i keep getting requests limits reached even though its first time I use the script on my main account, it work fine in my testing account which is normal Instagram account.

my code:

```
# DECLARING BOT INSTANCE
bot = Bot()
# END BLOCK
def post_instagram(id_):
row = check_if_exist(id_)
sub_title = row[1]
sub_link = row[2]
sub_status = row[3]
if sub_status == "FALSE":
    print(f'[INFO] Status is False, Ready To Upload')
    download_file(sub_title, sub_link)
    resize_pic(f'{BASE_PATH}\\images\\{sub_title}.jpg')
    if os.path.isfile(f"{BASE_PATH}\\config\\memelord6706_uuid_and_cookie.json"):
        os.remove(f"{BASE_PATH}\\config\\memelord6706_uuid_and_cookie.json")
    bot.login(username=config['account']['insta_user'], password=config['account']['insta_pass'])
    bot.upload_photo(f"{BASE_PATH}\\images\\{sub_title}.jpg", caption=sub_title)
    bot.logout()
    update_row(id_, "TRUE")
```

I know this library is not that popular but any help is well appreciated, thanks.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: don't you need some TOKEN or API_KEY to access it? If module uses some author's TOKEN or API_KEY then it is used by all users and it could reach limit.

Comment: which module do you mean [instabot](https://pypi.org/project/instabot/), [instabot-py](https://pypi.org/project/instabot-py/) or other?